# Is 导致 or 促使 better in 自负和冲动 [导致 / 促使] 了他的失败 ("arrogance and impulsion contributed to his failure")?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

If we are to translate "contributed to" in "someone's arrogance and impulsion contributed to his failure," should I use 导致 or 促使?

> 张三的自负和冲动**导致/促使**了他的失败。

Comment: 促使 seems a word as v.t. in english, i.e. use nouns and pronouns after the word 促使. Personally I would not say something like 促使了. When I say something like "his great dream drives him to work hard everyday", I may use 促使 as in 他远大的梦想促使他天天努力工作 [although my english sentence above would be flawed].

Comment: How about "自负和冲动促使张三失败"? Here, "了" has been removed.

Comment: Seems okay, but i would still use 导致. Anyway, everybody has preferences.

Comment: Don't you think 導致 means to cause something directly, whereas 促使 is more indirect?

Answer (score 3):

导 (lead) ; 致 (reach)

> 导致 = (lead to) **cause**

促 (induce); 使 (make)

> 促使 = (induce and make) **to push**

~

> "*someone's arrogance and impulsion **contributed** to his failure*"

'contributed' means 'helped' -- '导致 (lead to)' and "促使 (push)" are two different form of 'helping' something to happen, therefore, 导致 or 促使 are both acceptable in "张三的自负和冲动导致/促使了他的失败。"

If you want a strict word to word translation, you can use '作出贡献', but '贡献' in Chinese only denote contribution to 'positive result' For example: "对社会作出贡献" (contribute to society); but you cannot say "对失败作出贡献" (contribute to failure) unless this negative result is a good thing, for example: "對纳粹滅亡作出贡献" (contributed to the destruction of the Nazis)

导致 and 促使 doesn't have this problem, they can be used to describe contribution to 'positive or negative result'

Answer (score 2):

导致 implies “direct” cause. 促使 is more like “contributed to” in English. For this particular example, it’s better to use 促使

Answer (score 1):

In this case, **助力** is better to interpret "*contribute to*". 导致 and 促使 imply that arrogance and impulsion are the sufficient condition to lead to his failure. Well, "contribute to" doesn't imply a sufficient condition. In other words, his arrogance and impulsion are not the only reason to lead to his failure.

> "someone's arrogance and impulsion contributed to his failure," // 张三的自负和冲动助力了他的失败。

Comment: 助力 cannot be used as a verb in Mandarin.

Comment: @Apollyon, why not? I heard of lots of examples, like 他对于促进双方的协作助力不少；他的工作对于救灾助力甚大。他的工作助力甚大。

Comment: In your just-mentioned examples, which are indeed natural, 助力 is used with a particular frame: 对于 ... 助力甚大/助力不少.  "助力甚大/助力不少" is actually like an adjective. It like saying "这本书帮助很大," meaning "the book is immensely helpful."

Comment: @Apollyon I don't feel something unnatural about 张三的自负和冲动助力了他的失败 as a native speaker. You can also say 我的工作助力了祖国的四化建设.

Comment: @Apollyon There are lots of examples on the web. see this example: 181. 节目中一向冷面示人的涂磊转型做温情公益大使,“沈眉庄”扮演者斓曦与“春晚常客”金玉婷等四位明星观察员助力普通人圆梦。

Comment: @Apollyon refer to this link for more: http://m.zaojv.com/2501151_7.html

Comment: I don't know why 助力 would work. I might use 导致 in the sentence in the OP. Although lots of appearances of 助力 as a verb spotted on the web. Personally speaking, I myself would not use that. One other thing, 助力 seems better to indicate positive things. In the sentence above, that is a negative meaning. 导致 as "leads to" or "contribute to" might be better.

Comment: @xbh dosen't "contribute to" sound positive? Language is language, we can use it in a creative way. Can we use good words to describe the bad persons for some effects or vice versa?